# On-demand feature module not installed by default

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dynamic-feature-module

We have a dynamic feature module called `replay`. We started off making this an install-time module:

```
    <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/title_replay">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:install-time />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
    </dist:module>
```

when we installed the app locally:

`$ ./gradlew app:installDebug --info`

We see both base app and dynamic module installed:

```
Generating APKs for device 'Pixel 3a - 10' for app:debug
The APKs have been extracted in the directory: /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259
Installing APKs 'base-xxhdpi.apk, base-master_2.apk, base-en.apk, base-arm64_v8a_2.apk, replay-xxhdpi.apk, replay-master.apk' on 'Pixel 3a - 10' for app:debug
[SplitApkInstallerBase]: Created install session 1842207670 with options -r -t -S 12108428
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259/base-xxhdpi.apk to session 1842207670
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259/base-master_2.apk to session 1842207670
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259/base-en.apk to session 1842207670
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259/base-arm64_v8a_2.apk to session 1842207670
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259/replay-xxhdpi.apk to session 1842207670
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect7963605990779726259/replay-master.apk to session 1842207670
Installed on 1 device.
Task :app:installDebug in app Finished
```

However when we change to on-demand:

```
    <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/title_replay">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:on-demand />  THIS IS THE ONLY CHANGE
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
    </dist:module>
```

An install no longer installs dynamic apks:

`$ ./gradlew app:installDebug --info`

```
Generating APKs for device 'Pixel 3a - 10' for app:debug
The APKs have been extracted in the directory: /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect788484471691589897
Installing APKs 'base-xxhdpi.apk, base-master_2.apk, base-en.apk, base-arm64_v8a_2.apk' on 'Pixel 3a - 10' for app:debug
[SplitApkInstallerBase]: Created install session 745896174 with options -r -t -S 12031951
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect788484471691589897/base-xxhdpi.apk to session 745896174
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect788484471691589897/base-master_2.apk to session 745896174
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect788484471691589897/base-en.apk to session 745896174
[SplitApkInstaller]: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect788484471691589897/base-arm64_v8a_2.apk to session 745896174
Installed on 1 device.
```

How are we supposed to do this locally during development? Do we *have* to use `bundletool` to generate a universal apk? I assumed Android Plugin was smart enough to do all this for us.

Answer (score 1):

(Currently) in Android Studio, it only pre-installs the dynamic feature module (as selected in the modules dialog), when selecting "Default APK" instead of "APK from app bundle" for deployment, which might be caused by this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143503127).

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully there is a way to do this from CL too. For now we just use two separate AndroidManifest.xml for debug and release, with debug set to install-time and release set to on-demand